# How to Fix "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime" Error

Tags: python, windows, powershell, tensorflow, command-line

I'm trying to run I program I've written for Tensorflow from a file in Notepad using Powershell. Whenever I run `python main.py` to open and execute the code, I get the error below.

I haven't really found anything to try, and the only thing I felt I could do is uninstall and re-install Tensorflow, but that isn't working.

```
C:\Users\stxrsstillfade> cd tensorflow-demo
C:\Users\stxrsstillfade\tensorflow-demo> python main.py
```

The code error isn't even with the code. The traceback is saying that the problem is with the first line, `import tensorflow`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I've tried getting to the GitHub link, but it seems to have been deleted.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions from [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). I recommend please [install Tensorflow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow-2), if you are using lower versions.

To fix `Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime`, you need to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are facing any other issues possible reasons are

- Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) and [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).